# How to access props.children in a stateless functional component in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

The functional components in react are better to use if there aren't any internal state to be tracked within the component.

But what I want is to access the `children` of the stateless components without having to extend `React.Component` using which i can use `props.children`. Is this possible ?

If so , how to do it ?

Comment: Please explain your case further. What are you trying to achieve? A workable example would help. I don't see how stateful/stateless thing can affects `children` prop.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

We can use props.children in functional component. There is no need to use class based component for it.

```
const FunctionalComponent = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>I am inside functional component.</div>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
};
```

When you will call the functional component, you can do as follows -

```
const NewComponent = props => {
  return (
    <FunctionalComponent>
      <div>this is from new component.</div>
    </FunctionalComponent>
  );
};
```

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: I'd just add this in case you want to destructure object ES6 way

____

`const NewComponent = ({ children }) =>  <div> {children} </div> `

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to the answer by Ashish, you can destructure the "children" property in the child component using:

```
const FunctionalComponent = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>I am inside functional component.</div>
      { children }
    </div>
  );
};
```

This will allow you to pass along other props that you would like to destructure as well.

```
const FunctionalComponent = ({ title, content, children }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{ title }</h1>
      <div>{ content }</div>
      { children }
    </div>
  );
};
```

You can still use "props.title" etc to access those other props but its less clean and doesn't define what your component accepts.